# @postConstruct in JSF 1.1

Tags: jsf, icefaces, postconstruct

How do I simulate the `@postConstruct` behaviour in JSF 1.1 like as in JSF 1.2 and newer?

Actually, I want to call a bean method automatically during page loading?

I am using IceFaces 1.8 on JSF 1.1.

Answer (score 2):

The point of `@PostConstruct` is to provide a hook to execute some code *after* all managed properties (as in `<managed-property>` or `@ManagedProperty`) are been set and all dependency injections (e.g. `@EJB`, `@Resource`, `@Inject` and so on) have taken place.

If you don't have any of them, just use the bean's constructor.

```
public class Bean {

    public Bean() {
        // Just do your job here. Don't do it the hard way.
    }

    // ...
}
```

Or if you actually want to execute it when a specific property has been set, then do the job in the setter while null-checking the current property value.

```
public class Bean {

    private SomeObject someManagedProperty;

    public void setSomeManagedProperty(someManagedProperty) {
        if (this.someManagedProperty == null && someManagedProperty != null) {
            // First-time set, now you can do your job here.
        }

        this.someManagedProperty = someManagedProperty;
    }

    // ...
}
```

---

**Update** as per the comments:

> *I meant to execute the method every time the page is loaded*

The `@PostConstruct` doesn't do that. However, if the bean is request scoped, then you will see the same effect. You seem to be using a session or application scoped managed bean to manage request scoped data. This is in essence wrong. You should convert it to a request scoped bean. Any *real* session scoped data can be split into a session scoped bean which you then inject by `<managed-property>`.

Comment: Thank u man, but I meant to execute the method every time the page is loaded